# Visual Studio Code always opens "Getting Started" website and never remember "Opened Folders"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed VSCode 1.7.1 on OSX 10.11.6. Whenever I open VSCode, it always opens a "[Getting Started](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs?start=true)" tab in my browser. In addition, it never remembers any opened folders since my last session, even when my settings specify `"window.reopenFolders": "all"` or `"window.reopenFolders": "one"`. It's as if VSCode is always treating me as a brand new user.

I open VSCode by double-clicking on `Visual Studio Code.app` which is installed in `/Applications` (I am not starting it from some disk image).

How can I disable VSCode Gettings Started and have it remember opened folders from another session?